# File Manager with synchronized browsing

Tags: windows

I am looking for a Windows File Manager which supports the following features:

1. Synchronized browsing in dual pane view
2. TortoiseSVN icon overlays
3. Ability to quickly launch folder comparison in external tool such as
   Beyond Compare
4. Supports tabbed browsing
5. Supports saving the browsing session

The tool does not necessarily have to support all the features listed above.

Comment: Have you looked at SpeedCommander?

Comment: No, I have not. Would you like to add it to the answer and list what features it supports?

Comment: I found [Windows Double Explorer](http://wde.codeplex.com/) in a quick search; no experience with it, but it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks, Windows Double Explorer seems to have several features that I am looking for. Would you like to add it as an answer, or should I assume you want me to add it if you are giving your answer in a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Windows Double Explorer to be very useful.

It supports the following features:

1. TortoiseSVN icon overlays
2. Supports tabbed browsing
3. Supports saving the browsing session

Thanks to Luke for recommending it!